# My transformer doesn't work ( from model data to form data )

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, silex

I'm building a silex application (the source is [here](https://github.com/Mparaiso/Silex-Blog-App))
In the `App\Form\DataTransformer` I have a MetadataTransformer class.
But the `transform` method doesn't work (the reverse transform does).
It is applied to an `App\Form\Metadata AbstractType`, which is part of a collection in an `App\Form\ArticleForm AbstractType`.
The last form is called in the edit method of my `App\Controller\Admin\ArticleAdminController`

The data transformer is supposed to map a data like this

```
{"key":"value"}
```

Into a "form data" like :

```
[{"name":"key","value":"key"}]
```

So it can be displayed as a collection.

**Metadata.php**

```
class MetaData extends AbstractType
{
    protected $span4 = "span4";
    protected $span3 = "span3";

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder,array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                "label" => ' ',
                "attr"  => array(
                    "class"       => $this->span3,
                    "placeholder" => "name"
                )
            ))
            ->add('value', 'text', array(
                'label' => ' ',
                'attr'  => array(
                    "class"       => $this->span4,
                    'placeholder' => 'value'
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "MetaData";
    }
}
```

**ArticleForm.php**

```
class ArticleForm extends AbstractType
{
    // ...some code...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new TagsToArrayTransformer();
        $metadataTransformer = new MetadataTransformer();

        $builder->add("title", "text", array(
            "required" => true,
            "attr"     => array(
                "class"       => $this->defaultClass,
                "placeholder" => "The title"
            )
        ));
        $builder->add("content", "textarea", array(
            "attr" => array(
                "placeholder" => "the content",
                "rows"        => 20,
                "class"       => $this->defaultClass
            )
        ));
        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('metadatas', 'collection', array(
                "type"         => new MetaData(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
            ->addModelTransformer($metadataTransformer)
        );

        // ...some code...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "article";
    }
}
```

My data transformer should look like :

**MetadataTransformer.php**

```
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class MetadataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    function transform($metadatas)
    {
        foreach($metadatas as $key => $value) {
            $result[] = array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function reverseTransform($metadatas)
    {
        if(is_array($metadatas)) {
            foreach($metadatas as $value) {
                $result[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
            }

            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

The reverseTransform works, but the transfom itself doesn't seem to.
The goal here is to be able to display a dynamic collection in a form (add and remove metadatas dynamically in my article form page)

In the repo I add to change the code to make it work (i.e. transforming the datas in the controller ArticleAdminController, instead of doing it in the Transformer)
If I log the result of the transform at runtime, the result is what I expect, but the form won't use it.

I tried already the addViewTransformer / addModelTransformer 2.1 api but it did not make any difference.

**So how what's wrong with my model data -> to -> form data transform ?**

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I unfortunately have a similar problem. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form type is collection and your transformer returns an array.  You need to recast it.  Try:

```
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer{
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
class MetadataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface{

function transform($metadatas){
  foreach($metadatas as $key=>$value):
    $result[]=array('name'=>$key,'value'=>$value);
  endforeach;
  $results=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($result);
  return $results;
}

function reverseTransform($metadatas){
  if(is_array($metadatas)){
    foreach($metadatas as $value){
      $result[$value['name']]=$value['value'];
    }
    return $result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Had you tried this :

```
function transform($metadatas) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($metadatas as $key => $value) {
        $results['name'] = $key;
        $results['value'] = $value;
    }
    return $results;
}
```