# Data model transformer for Collection form type in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have such task as described in this question: [My transformer doesn't work ( from model data to form data )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492775/my-transformer-doesnt-work-from-model-data-to-form-data)

Currently i work with symfony 2.2.4 and unfortunately answers doesn't work for me with following error: `The name "Цвет" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").`

My custom form type:

```
class KeyValueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('key', 'text', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('value', 'text', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'key_value';
    }
}
```

My data:

```
array(
    'Цвет' => 'Red'
);
```

and use my form type:

```
$transformer = new AssocArrayToKeyValueTransformer;

$builder->add(
    $builder->create('values', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new KeyValueType(),
        'required' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true
    ))
    ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
```

After some digging i saw that FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA events triggered before model transformations https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L321, and for collection form type there is ResizeEventListener.

So i write some hack:

```
$transformer = new AssocArrayToKeyValueTransformer;

$builder->add(
    $builder->create('modification_values', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new KeyValueType(),
        'required' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true
    ))
    ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $result = array();
        if ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $result[] = array(
                    'key' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                );
            }
        }

        $event->setData($result);
    }, 1)
);
```

Ideas is i change my data in PRE_SET_DATA event with priority = 1 (which is greater then ResizeFormListener has) and that means that i use my transformer only for reverse transform. Work great but feel really hacky. Can you provide me with better solution? Is it bug of symfony2?

Comment: Have you try to use non Cyrillic key in array?

Comment: This is old, but I'll still comment: isn't `'type' => KeyValueType()` supposed to be `'type' => new KeyValueType()` ?

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I'm curious if you ever found a less hacky solution to this problem? Did you ever report it to Symfony?